# Problema al enviar datos ajax php

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, ajax

Hola a todos les pido ayuda ya que estoy haciendo un pequeño proyecto en laravel y lo que quiero hacer es que cuando un usuario escriba un email con el que quiere registrarse lo que voy a hacer es que se envié una petición ajax a php para ver si el email es único, esto lo hago mediante la funcion `onblur` desde la cual llamo a mi funcion de `validate`, lo malo es que creo que ajax no recibe los datos que retorna php, esta es la forma en la que incluyo jquery:

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256- H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Esta es mi ruta de php:

```
Route::get('/validate-email/{email}', [App\Http\Controllers\ValidateController::class, 'email']);
```

Y este es mi controlador con el que recibo el email y veo si existe en la base de datos:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\UserTable;

class ValidateController extends Controller
{
    public function email($email)
    {
        $validate = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

        if($validate)
        {
            $nicknames = UserTable::where('email', "=", $email)
                                    ->count();

            if($nicknames == 0)
            {
                return response()->json([
                    'value' => true
                ]);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Hasta ahí cuando abro la página todo esta bien ya que si me regresa de forma correcta el json, y por último este es mi código js:

```
var url = "url_de_mi_proyecto/";

function validate(input)
{
    if(input.value == "")
    {
        return "";
    }
    else
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: url+'validate-email/'+input.value,
            type: 'GET',
            succes: function(data)
            {
                if(data.value == true)
                {
                    alert('alert de prueba correcto')
                }
                else
                {
                    alert('alert de prueba erronea')
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
</script>
```

Cuando hago eso no me muestra ningún alert, alguien me puede decir que estoy haciendo mal, quiero aclarar que no se mucho de jquery por lo que no se si lo estoy haciendo de la forma correcta o si el error es relativamente básico. Desde ya gracias :).

### Actualización

Algunas persones me dijeron que pusiera un alert dentro del success o al inicio de la función, cuando lo pongo al inicio todo esta bien y si recibe los datos que quiero recibir pero si lo pongo adentro del success no pasa nada por lo que creo que tampoco esta entrando en el succes

Comment: Puedes hacer console.log(data) dentro del succes y antes del if?

Comment: Si no muestra ninguno de los alert es porque no está entrando en el `success` o quizá ni siquiera en el `else` que lanzaría tu petición Ajax. Revisa la consola en busca de algún error, allí debería decirte por qué no está funcionando el código. Dado que tienes una verificación inicial, convendría también que pongas esto al inicio de la función: `console.log(input);` para verificar que no está retornando al estar vacío el valor de tu parámetro `input`.

Comment: @Vicent al hacer lo que dijiste sigue sin retornarme nada, no veo ningún cambio en la consola después de hacer eso

Comment: @A.Cedano al hacer el `console.log(input);` me devuelve todo bien, e incluso al hacer `console.log(input.value);` si me devuelve el valor del input, pero en la consola no tengo ningún error relacionado a este archivo, solo errores del **app.js** de laravel

Comment: Añade la parte de `error` a tu petición Ajax, puede que algo esté fallando en el servidor y la única forma de saberlo es capturando el error.

Comment: @A.Cedano ¿A que te refieres con la parte de error?, porque no me genera ningún error por el momento este archivo

Comment: Así como `$.ajax` tiene una función `success` para cuando la petición funciona, puedes incorporar una función `error` para controlar posibles fallos (por ejemplo errores de red o de servidor). Así podrás saber si tu código estaría fallando por alguno de esos motivos. Sería incorporar algo así a tu Ajax: `error: function(xhr, status, error) {
  alert(error);
}`  debajo del `callback` del `success` [Aquí tienes un ejemplo completo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8918298/5587982).

Comment: @A.Cedano intente lo que dijiste tanto con el ejemplo completo con el que me pasaste, y literalmente no paso nada, en ninguna parte de la pagina vi cambios, ¿tiene que ver la forma en la que lo paso desde php, o tambien tiene que ver la forma en la que lo hago con el `onblur`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

copie tu código y lo implemente, el error del código de que no te entra al success es debido a que te falta una letra en el sucess la ultima 's'

```
succes: function(data) aquí (success)
```

ahora bien hice algunas modificaciones que me están funcionando, si tu quieres lo puedes implementar

La ruta le agregue un name y le quite el parámetro que recibe

```
Route::get('/validate-email', [App\Http\Controllers\principal_controller::class, 'email'])->name('validar_email');
```

el controlador recibe los datos por el request

```
public function email(Request $request)
{
    $validate = filter_var($request->get('email'), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    if($validate)
    {
        $nicknames = User::where('email', "=", $request->get('email'))
            ->first();

        return ($nicknames)?1:0; //si existe devuelvo 1 si no un 0
    }
}
```

y el ajax le envió los datos por el data

```
function validar_correo(input)
    {
        if(input.value == "")
        {
            return "";
        }
        else
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{route('validar_email')}}',
                data:{
                    'email':input.value
                },
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(data)
                {
                    if(data==='1')
                        alert('El correo ya existe');
                    else
                        alert('El correo no existe');
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hola, intente de lo que dijiste y casi todo va bien, lo malo es que me genera este error `jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2 GET http://localhost/laravell/public/validate-email?email=sda%40xn--safd-zua.com 500 (Internal Server Error)`, el codigo es el mismo, ¿porque pasa eso? y ¿como lo puedo solucionar?

Comment: @DavidFloresGarcía copiastes el código tal cual lo puse?

Comment: Si, esta exactamente igual

Comment: bueno tenias que hacer cambios en la ruta, si te fijas mi controlador se llama principal_controller, ahi lo tienes que cambiar por el tuyo que es ValidateController, por eso te lanza el error ya q ese controlador no existe en tu proyecto

Comment: Jajaj gracias, no vi esa parte, ya acepte tu respuesta :)

Comment: de nada amigo, suerte

Comment: Mañana te doy tu recompensa, ahorita no me deja me dice que la voy a poder otorgar dentro de 21 horas

Answer (score 0):

el año pasado estuve haciendo proyectos y espero poder echarte una mano, lo primero que veo es a la hora de hacer la llamada a AJAX  `$.post({`
utilizas post, si no me equivoco se tiene que usar `$.ajax`.Success es con dos s. No se si el orden de los parametros importa pero yo dejaría algo asi:

```
$.ajax({                        
       type: "GET",                 
       url: url+'validate-email/'+input.value,                    
       success: function(data)            
       {
         if(data) //Al  ser un valor boolean, no hace falta compararlo con ser correcto
            {
                alert('alert de prueba correcto')
            }
            else
            {
                alert('alert de prueba erronea')
            }         
       }
```

Suerte, prueba y si ves algun otro fallo avisame. Tambien te recomiendo mirar en el inspeccionador de red del google chrome y ver los datos que envias[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, lo intente como dijiste y sigue sin funcionar, no me muestra nada